# What software to use to generate bandwidth graphs in real time?

Tags: centos, bandwidth, snmp

What sofware could I use to monitor my server's bandwidth in realtime, or at least, update every x minutes.

My server (dell r620) is connected to a routerboard Mikrotik rb1200.
But, as my router is set to behave like a switch, it does not allow to monitor the traffic on the port the server is connected to.

The only solution I think would be to install a snmp server on the server.
What do you recommend?

[image]

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic on all [SE] sites. Please refer to the [FAQ] and [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) blog entry explaining this further.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Cacti or Icinga w/ PNP4Nagios if you're a fan of OSS, otherwise, look at SolarWinds Orion.

Answer (score -2):

check out http://www.logicmonitor.com/ - not sure how well it works with linux - works great with firewalls and windows WHMI